# Is it possible to impersonate a user from different hosts?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

I want to impersonate a user from different hosts.

I have 2 security files because my project is divided in 2 parts. One for admin and one for user.

My Admin firewall
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/

## user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker

```
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: easyadmin
```

## failure_handler: 'user.login_error.handler'

```
            remember_me: true
            use_forward: true
```

## always_use_default_target_path: true

```
        remember_me:
            secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
            always_remember_me: false
        switch_user:
            provider: ~
            role: ROLE_ADMIN
            parameter: _switch_user
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous: true
```

My user firewall
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/

## user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker

```
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: easyadmin
```

## failure_handler: 'user.login_error.handler'

```
            remember_me: true
            use_forward: true
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        remember_me:
            secret: "%env(APP_SECRET)%"
            lifetime: 31536000
            path:     /
            domain:   ~
            always_remember_me: false

        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous: true
    admin:
        pattern:            /admin
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /admin/login
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin/
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:         /admin/login
        anonymous:    true
```

Currently if I'm logged in as an admin, I can't access the user host, I want to be able to access the user host, using an admin account from a separate host.

Admin Host : `http://admin.un.dev`
User Hosts: `http://user.un.dev`

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand fully. You have an admin account on one host, and you want to access a separate host using that admin account?

Answer (score 0):

You can’t... the session cookies are set per domain. You could do it if they are on the same host, but on different paths: abc.com/admin and abc.com/user